# QML ComboBox Witth CheckBox

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qt5

I Want to Design ComboBox(Dynamic) in Qml having checkbox in it.
when i will check thecheckbox which is in combobox, i want to add a element in listview which under the combox.
please help me with that

example image is attached below

[image]

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: applicationWindow
    visible: true;
    width: screen.width;
    height: screen.height;




    ComboBox {
        id: comboBox
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height/20
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right

        anchors.leftMargin: 40
        anchors.rightMargin: 40
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 10
        onCurrentIndexChanged: {
            var receivedData = {
                imageSource: "bulb",
                loadType: "Light",
                loadName: "▶BedRoom1",
                loadStatus: false,
                macId: "00:17:F1:00:00:B8_01",
            };
            var receivedData1 = {
                imageSource: "ac",
                loadType: "AC",
                loadName: "▶BedRoom21",
                loadStatus: true,
                macId: "00:17:F1:00:00:B8_02",
            };

            var receivedData2 = {
                imageSource: "dimmer",
                loadType: "Dimmer",
                loadName: "▶Hall1",
                loadStatus: false,
                macId: "00:17:F1:00:00:B8_03",
            };
            var receivedData3 = {
                imageSource: "fan",
                loadType: "Fan",
                loadName: "▶Hall1",
                loadStatus: false,
                macId: "00:17:F1:00:00:B8_04",
            };


            console.debug(combomodel.get(currentIndex).text)
            if(combomodel.get(currentIndex).text === "Light")
            {
                loadListView(receivedData)
            }
            else if(combomodel.get(currentIndex).text === "Bulb")
            {
                loadListView(receivedData)
            }
            else if(combomodel.get(currentIndex).text === "Ac")
            {
                loadListView(receivedData1)
            }
            else if(combomodel.get(currentIndex).text === "Dimmer")
            {
                loadListView(receivedData2)
            }
            else if(combomodel.get(currentIndex).text === "Fan")
            {
                loadListView(receivedData3)
            }

        }



        model: ListModel {
            id:combomodel
            ListElement {
                //text:"Select Device"
                name: ""
                checked: false
            }

        }
        function loadListView({imageSource,loadType,loadName,loadStatus,macId})
        {

            listmodel.append({"src": imageSource,"load":loadType,"label" : loadName,"checkedStatus" : loadStatus,"macStatus" :macId })
        }

        delegate: Item {
            width: parent.width
            implicitHeight: checkDelegate.implicitHeight

            CheckDelegate {
                id: checkDelegate
                width: parent.width
                text: model.name
                highlighted: comboBox.highlightedIndex === index
                checked: model.checked
                onCheckedChanged:
                {
                    model.checked = checked

                }

            }
        }


    }


    function appendData()
    {
        combomodel.append({ "name":"S" } )
        combomodel.append({ "name":"U" } )
        combomodel.append({ "name":"R" } )
        combomodel.append({ "name":"A" } )
        combomodel.append({ "name":"J" } )
        combomodel.append({ "name":"T" } )


    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        getModuleTableData()
    }

    ListView {
        id:listview
        anchors.top: comboBox.bottom
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.leftMargin: 5
        anchors.rightMargin: 5
        anchors.topMargin: 10
        flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick
        boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
        clip: true

        //delegate: deviceDelegate

        model: ListModel{
            id:listmodel
        }
        focus: true
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {}
    }

    Dbadaptor{
        id:dbadaptor
    }
    function getModuleTableData()
    {
        console.log("In getModuleTableData() function")
        var data = dbadaptor.fetchModuleTable()
        console.log("Data: ",data)
        console.log("length",data.length)
        for(var i = 0; i< data.length;i++)
        {
            console.log("Name: ",data[i])
            //if(data[i] == "")
            combomodel.append({"name": '<b>'+data[i]+'</b>',"ckecked": ""})
            var dataload = dbadaptor.fetchLoadDataForGroup(i+1)
            console.log("loadData :",dataload)
            console.log("loaddatalength: ",dataload.length)
            for(var j = 0; j<dataload.length;j++)
            {
                combomodel.append({"name" : dataload[j],"checked": false})
            }
        }

    }
}
```

In above code i am appending data in ComboBox with checkbox,when i click on CheckBox,I want to print a debug Message.
And in ComboBox where 8x1 device name is there i dont want to append checkBox with respect to it.

Comment: If you want someone to write all the code for you then you've chosen the wrong site. Please provide your attempt to solve the issue, what was the expected goal and what was the result. Show specific errors, the difficulties etc. Please read how to create [mcve] and [ask]. Maybe the folowing articles can help you: [Models and Views in Qt Quick](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html), [QML Dynamic Objects](https://wiki.qt.io/QML_Dynamic_Objects)

Comment: @folibis,I am adding My Code.I will Update My query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is wrap the corresponding property as an object and append into the list model during the `onCheckChanged` slot of the checkbox. Here is a sample code that may help to achieve the above things.

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: applicationWindow
    visible: true;
    width: 640
    height: 480

    ComboBox {
        id: comboboxId
        width: parent.width / 2
        height: 50
        model: ListModel {
            ListElement { name: "One"; fill: "red"; ischecked: true }
            ListElement { name: "Two"; fill: "green"; ischecked: false }
            ListElement { name: "Three"; fill: "blue"; ischecked: false }
        }
        delegate: Item {
            width: parent.width
            height: 50
            Row {
                spacing: 5
                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.margins: 5
                CheckBox {
                    id: checkboxId
                    height: parent.height
                    width: height
                    onPressed: checked = !checked
                    onCheckedChanged: {
                        if(checked)
                        {
                            listmodelId.append({ "name": name, "fill": fill })
                        }
                    }
                }
                Label {
                    text: name
                    width: parent.width - checkboxId.width
                    height: parent.height
                    verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
                    horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ListModel {
        id: listmodelId
    }

    ListView {
        width: parent.width / 2
        height: parent.height
        anchors.left: comboboxId.right
        model: listmodelId
        delegate: Item {
            height: 50
            width: parent.width
            Rectangle {
                anchors.fill: parent
                color: fill
                Text {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    text: name
                }
            }
        }
        onCountChanged: console.log(count)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ramkumar R, You have Given me exact solution But,I want to remove the data appended in listview if i uncheck the checkBox,In your code,If i check the checkbox,it is not checking,but it is adding in Listview if i click on it.I want to add data on check of checkbox and remove too if i uncheck it.

Comment: Removal of data can be done through the [remove](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#remove-method) method. But in your case, since we can't predict the index you have to go through the entire list model data match with your unique key(whatever it is based on your requirement) of property get the index of it and then remove. That's is the least possible approach we can do for it.

Answer (score 1):

QML's combobox by default uses MenuItem as delegate:

```
delegate: MenuItem {
        width: ListView.view.width
        text: control.textRole ? (Array.isArray(control.model) ? modelData[control.textRole] : model[control.textRole]) : modelData
        Material.foreground: control.currentIndex === index ? ListView.view.contentItem.Material.accent : ListView.view.contentItem.Material.foreground
        highlighted: control.highlightedIndex === index
        hoverEnabled: control.hoverEnabled
    }
```

And MenuItem has a property checkable. So you can override the delegate and use a checkable one:

```
    ComboBox{
        id: combo_value

        delegate:MenuItem {
            width: ListView.view.width
            text: combo_value.textRole ? (Array.isArray(combo_value.model) ? modelData[combo_value.textRole] : model[combo_value.textRole]) : modelData
            Material.foreground: combo_value.currentIndex === index ? ListView.view.contentItem.Material.accent : ListView.view.contentItem.Material.foreground
            highlighted: combo_value.highlightedIndex === index;
            hoverEnabled: combo_value.hoverEnabled

            checkable: true
        }
    }
```